# Is there a solution to automate the versioning of an API inside a spring project?

Tags: java, spring, azure-devops, version-control, azure-pipelines

I would like to **automate** the **process** **of changing the version of the API I use in my java project** (from the pom.xml) and build the project automatically in a branch on Azure DevOps.

I'm working on a java project right now, and I'm using another external project (equivalent of API to communicate with another application). What I do at the moment is manually check the current API version (external project) that I see on my Azure DevOps dashboard (Screenshot bellow), and I manually change on my pom.xml from my java project. What I want: Automate this process so that after each new version of the API, the build of the new version on my project is done automatically without intervention and on a separate branch for example
[Azure dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRRFv.png)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Changing versions of dependencies (I guess that's what you mean) could break things and you may have to fix your code. I'd try this on my local dev machine for faster feedback. Or is this the version of the code you are building, not using? In that case, how would you know the new version number, especially if you want to (and you should IMHO) follow [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). I guess I just don't understand what you are trying to do. Did you see [ask]?

Comment: I'll try to be more specific: I'm working on a java project right now, and I'm using another external project (equivalent of API to communicate with another application).

What I do at the moment is manually check the current API version (external project) that I see on my Azure DevOps dashboard (Screenshot above), and I manually change on my pom.xml from my java project.

What I want: Automate this process so that after each new version of the API, the build of the new version on my project is done automatically without intervention and on a separate branch for example

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Replace Tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens&ssr=false#overview) in the build pipeline for the source project (or you mean "external project") and replace the version of the API in your java project (from the pom.xml) with the variable [`$(Build.BuildNumber)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

the build pipeline for the source project:
[image]